# Only allow one unique foreign key for primary

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in mysql, One is a Company table, the other is a license table and the last is a joining table between both primary keys, When a person adds a company id to the license id in the joining table, it allows multiple companies to exist for one license, this cannot happen, so I need to do something that will only allow one company id for one license id

heres the tables

Table license

```
    CREATE TABLE `License` (
  `license_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `license_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `expiry_date` date NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`license_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
;
```

Company Table

```
    CREATE TABLE `Company` (
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `physical_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postal_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reseller_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`company_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=18 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and Joining table

```
    CREATE TABLE `CompanyLicense` (
  `license_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`license_id`,`company_id`),
  KEY `companlicence_company_fk_idx` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `companylicense_company_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `Company` (`company_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `companylicense_license_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`license_id`) REFERENCES `License` (`license_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

So far i have this

```
INSERT INTO CompanyLicense (license_id, company_id) VALUES
('2','6') on duplicate key update license_id = '2';
```

doesnt seem to do the job

Comment: the heading is badly written

Comment: If you can only have only one company per license, why not make `company` a field in `license`?

Comment: that actually will work

Comment: The whole reason for this is that once a person adds a company to a license, that change must not be editable, this is all done in javascript, sencha, but i thought that this might solve at least part of the problem

Comment: Adding a "joining" table to show the relationship should only be done for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: what could be used for a one to many relationship

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `company` unique in `companylicense`:

```
ALTER TABLE companylicense ADD UNIQUE KEY (company)
```

or better yet, make `company` a field in `license` instead of having a link table.

Comment: yes I had the joining table and I could have done the unique key, but I just put the company_id field into the license table